# Is a spouse of a US permanent resident exempt from the travel ban? I am a U.K. passport holder

Tags: usa, esta, covid-19, spouses, travel-ban

Two questions;

1. Are spouses of permanent residents currently allowed to travel to the US? I want to get back to my husband as I do not want to be separated at the moment.
2. If they are exempt, how do I go about getting an ESTA or would it be better to have another type of visa? My ESTA was cancelled when the travel ban came into place.

Thanks in advance.